# OWIN Web API authorization in User Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I prepare User Interface in MVC and Web API. Authorization in Web API via OWIN is correct. In login method you can see I just log on to Web API and I take some information token etc. but is it possible import this autorization from Web API and add this to Interface in MVC? If yes how to do it?

For example: mvcUI.User = WebAPI.User

*I would like to use also [Authorize], claims in mvcUI

[image]

used WebApiAuthorizationHelper code:

```
 public static class WebApiAuthorizationHelper
    {

        public static string GetToken(string url, string userName, string password)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", userName ),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "Password", password )
                    };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.PostAsync(url + "Token", content).Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        public static string CallApi(string url, string token)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(token);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + t.access_token);
                }
                var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        class Token
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public int expires_in { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(".issued")]
            public string issued { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(".expires")]
            public string expires { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think we have a similar setup. You can achieve what you want by decoding the token on the MVC side, reading its claims and on the MVC side, add use cookie authentication. Store the same values of the token in the cookie on the MVC side and then you will be able to use the [Authorize] attribute. Security is then done by the cookie but undirectly by the jwt token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add information in token that code below.

**My CustomIdentityService**

```
public class CustomIdentityService
{
   protected MyContext _context = new MyContext();

   public Guid FooInfo(Guid IdentityUserID)
   {
    return con.fooTable.Where(x => x.IdentityUserID == IdentityUserID).
    Select(us => new { us.fooData }).FirstOrDefault().fooData;
   }
 }
```

**Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs**

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

    CustomIdentityService _customIdentityService = new CustomIdentityService();

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    //Add custom claims code
    string fooInfo= _customIdentityService.FooInfo(user.Id));
    oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("fooInfo", fooInfo));
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName,fooInfo);

    }

  public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName,string fooInfo)
    {
       IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
        { "fooInfo", fooInfo },
        { "userName", userName }
     };
       return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
     }
```

Comment: I found solution when @Verthosa write http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1 but also your answer is correct